# Errors when running accumulo init

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I have Hadoop and Zookeeper running w/o a problem but when I go to run `$ACCUMULO_HOME/bin/accumulo init`, this happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/start/Platform
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.accumulo.start.Platform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/start/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.accumulo.start.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I can't see to find anything helpful.

Comment: Does `$ACCUMULO_HOME/bin/accumulo classpath` also yield the same error?

Comment: I seemed to have downloaded the source instead of the binaries and forgot to build it.  After I ran mvn package, It worked.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when trying to run from the source code without compiling it with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this may have been resolved by now?

If not, looks like Accumulo has not been compiled correctly.

If your using the Binary Dist, run the following to compile.

> mvn package -P assemble